# Multer/Nodejs - Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a script that allows me to upload files into a folder using React on the frontend and Node on the backend.

I have a folder named `client` and another named `server`. When I click on `upload file`, the file is uploaded.

So what I did is create a new project and moved just the backend, keeping `client` in the old one. Now, when I click on `upload image`, I get this error and I don"t know why:

[image: Error screenshot]

Maybe there is something wrong with Multer?

---

**Code:**

**`server`**

```
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "uploads/",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "IMAGE-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 1000000 },
}).single("file");

exports.filesU = (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    console.log("Request ---", req.body);
    console.log("Request file ---", req.file);
    //Here you get file.
    /*Now do where ever you want to do*/
    if (!err) return res.json({ success: true, url: res.req.file.path });
  });
};
```

**`client`**

```
let formdData = new FormData();
const config = {
  header: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
};

formdData.append("file", files[0]);
console.log(formdData);

Axios.post(
  "http://localhost:4000/api/chat/uploadfiles",
  formdData,
  config
)
```

Comment: yeah I've just change the directory locations  nothing else, also on 4000

Comment: try logging `res.req`

Comment: in this file `res.req` is undefined and on the other file where the client is located `file: {
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'conception-de-logo-d-icône-vecteur-pose-combat-art-martial-karaté-136656715.jpg',        
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'uploads/',
    filename: 'IMAGE-1611007225124.jpg',
    path: 'uploads\\IMAGE-1611007225124.jpg',
    size: 32286
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}`

Comment: Can you please delete node_module folder and try to install npm again and check.

Comment: I deleted the node_Modules and same result `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: Please Anyone can help me on this ? @Daniel_Knights

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what the issue is from what you've posted. Could you add any more info? Filetree, `package.json`, how you're running your server etc., just anything you think might be useful